# Laravel 5.6 Route Group

Tags: php, laravel

My controllers which are HomeController and BlogController in Admin folder. My views like:

- /admin

  - index.blade.php
  - /blog

    - index.blade.php

I want to call /admin0admin url to /resources/views/admin/index.blade.php.

I want to call /admin0admin/blog url to /resources/views/admin/blog/index.blade.php

Here how i call in view:

```
<a href="{{ route('admin0admin.blog') }}" class="br-menu-link">
```

And my routes like:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin0admin'], function () {
     Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('index');

     Route::group(['prefix' => 'blog'], function () {
         Route::get('/', 'BlogController@index')->name('index');
     });
});
```

And my BlogController index method:

```
return view('admin.blog.index');
```

I got an 404 not found error.

> Route [admin0admin.blog] not defined

**Laravel Version is : 5.6.***

[image]

Comment: Check out `php artisan route:list` to find out what the names and routes are in your app.

Comment: i added route list too

Comment: there is your issue! You need to name the route `admin0admin.blog`, not `index`. `prefix` does not affect names of routes, so you need to write it out.

Comment: can you write as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name the route `admin0admin.blog`, not `index`. `prefix` does not affect names of routes, so you need to write it out.